# How to do Geo tagging of Houses photos in arcgis software?

Tags: gis, qgis, arcgis-server

I have 4000 house photos and with out latitude and longitude on photo header but each and every house latitude and longitude in stored in excel file. 
I already used www.geoimgr.com website , photo uploaded and manually enter lat/long values on photo and more time taken this process because is it any method or code for sample done process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the EXIF Data of the images. 
Check this link for sample code:  [How can I add EXIF information to geotag an Image in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305848/how-can-i-add-exif-information-to-geotag-an-image-in-net)